# Enable datepicker for HTML table in Django

Tags: django, html-table

I have an HTML table in a Django template. This table consists of three columns: start date, stop date and difference between the two. **I want to include a date-picker above that allows me to set a "From" and "To" date and get the overall records for that particular time period**. How can I do this?

**models.py:**

```
class Startdate(models.Model):
    user_id= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()

class Stopdate(models.Model):
    user_id= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    stop_time = models.DateTimeField()
    diff = models.DurationField(null = True, blank=True)
```

**views.py:**

```
def interface(request):
    data = User.objects.filter(pk__gt=1) #All users apart from the SuperUser admin
    store_data = []
    for user in data:
        sta_time = Startdate.objects.filter(user_id = user)
        sta_data = sta_time.values_list('start_time', flat=True)

        sto_time = Stopdate.objects.filter(user_id = user)
        sto_data = sto_time.values_list('stop_time', flat=True)
        diff_data = sto_time.values_list('diff', flat = True)

        store_data.append((sta_data, sto_data, diff_data))
    return render(request, 'users/interface.html', {'data': store_data})
```

**interface.html:**

```
<table>
    <tr>

        <th> Start Time </th> 
        <th> Stop Time </th>
        <th> Difference </th>
    </tr>
        {% for column in data %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{column.0}}</td>
            <td>{{column.1}}</td>
            <td>{{column.2}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}

 </table>
```

How do I include a date picker for the table, above? Also, how can I implement the functionality to set a From and To date and get back those rows between the chosen time period?

Answer (score 0):

Try include this in your main html.

```
 <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- XDSoft DateTimePicker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-DOS9W6NR+NFe1fUhEE0PGKY/fubbUCnOfTje2JMDw3Y=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" integrity="sha256-FEqEelWI3WouFOo2VWP/uJfs1y8KJ++FLh2Lbqc8SJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Add this code in interface.html this also shows different days between two date

```
 <input  class="datetimepicker"  name="start_date" id="start_date" type="text">
  <input class="datetimepicker" name="end_date" id="end_date"  type="text" onchange="myFunction()">
  <div>
    <span id="FinalDateDiff"></span>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(function () {
      $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
    });
    function myFunction() {
       var start = $('#start_date').val();
       var end = $('#end_date').val();
       console.log(start);
       console.log(end);
           var startDay = new Date(start);
           var endDay = new Date(end);
           var millisecondsPerDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

           var millisBetween = endDay.getTime() - startDay.getTime();
           var days = millisBetween / millisecondsPerDay;
      $('#FinalDateDiff').html(days);
     }

  </script>
```

To calculate date diff

```
var start = $('#start_date').val();
var end = $('#end_date').val();

var date_diff = new Date(end - start);
```

Comment: Does it filter the dates in my table?

Comment: what is {{form.date}} here?

Comment: I remove unwanted added only what you need

Comment: I am able to set the From and To dates, but how can I filter my table rows (filled with time logs) with it?